# Any expiry for Public and Private key created from SecKeyGeneratePair? (iOS - Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, private, public

Writing pertaining the development on iOS-Swift platform.
I have created a public and private key in the usage of biometric authentication between server and my device. However, I do not see any library or keyword to check or configure the expiry.

The Public and Private key are created from SecKeyGeneratePair.
Are there any date expiry?

Comment: What makes you think there is an expiration date?

Comment: Public and private key created in java and desktop has its expiry or rather, I can set my expiry date. But I do not see one for iOS Swift. That makes me wonder.

Comment: Key pairs (private/public) don't have expiration date, usually, but certificates (made from them and containing the public key). I'm assuming that you only have a key pair without a certificate and that is the reason of no expiration date. Hope this clear things out.

Comment: That explains.
I believed Java KeyPairGenerator using different approach that iOS.
Many thanks fjsv